# Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.sendMessages is not a function in Chrome Extension Development

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension using manifest 3. I have a timer in the popup HTML page which is triggered when the button is pressed. I realized that the timer resets every time the popup is opened whereas I want it to remain running in the background.

So I thought the only answer would be to tie the popup page to the background.js. I created a state for the timer called pomo_state. Then I send a message from the popup.js to the background.js which either turns the state to OFF or ON depending on the button pressed by the user in the popup page. Then I am planning to run the timer in the background and dynamically update the popup.html every time it is opened by having it retrieve the timer from the background.

But I couldn't even get past the sending and receiving of the pomo_state. I got the error in the title. And when I changed it to chrome.extensions.runtime.sendMessages, I got an error saying message was undefined or something like that. Also right now in my popup.js I have the timer code for now, but putting it in the background.js will be another problem since I got an error for background.js not registering in the manifest when I did that. Also I should say that looking at other questions that had the same error, I couldn't really find a concrete answer. And I was wondering what I am screwing up below is probably really basic.

I will attach part of my background.js, popup.html and popup.js. Hopefully it will be sufficient. Thanks!

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) =>{
    if (request.message === 'get_name'){
        chrome.storage.local.get('name', data =>{
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError){
                sendResponse({
                    message: 'fail'
                });
                return;
            }
            sendResponse({
                message: 'success',
                payload: data.name
            })
        });
        return true;
    } else if (request.message === 'pomo_change'){
        chrome.storage.local.set({
            pomo:request.payload
        }, () => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError){
                sendResponse({message: 'fail'});
                return;
            }
            sendResponse({message: 'success'});
        })
        return true;
    }
});
```

popup.js

```
const start_pom = document.getElementById("start_pom");

let colorSwitchCounter = 1;
const startingMinutes = 25;
let time = startingMinutes*60;
const countdownEl = document.getElementById("countdown-timer");

setInterval(updateCountdown,1000);

function updateCountdown(){
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time%60;
    countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
    console.log(`${minutes}: ${seconds}`);
    time--;
}
start_pom.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    console.log("I was clicked", colorSwitchCounter);
    colorSwitchCounter = colorSwitchCounter +1;
    if(colorSwitchCounter%2 ==0){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            message: 'pomo_change',
            payload: 'ON'

        }, response =>{
            if (response.message === 'success'){
                start_pom.innerHTML= 'Stop Pomodoro';
                start_pom.style.backgroundColor = "#de7878";
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        chrome.runtime.sendMessages({
            message: 'pomo_change',
            payload: 'OFF'
        }, response =>{
            if (response.message === 'success'){
                start_pom.innerHTML= 'Start Pomodoro';
                start_pom.style.backgroundColor = "#de7878";
            }
        });
    }
})
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            padding:0px;
            height: wrap-content;
            width: 255px;
            background-color: whitesmoke;
        }
        section{
            padding:10px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .hero-area{
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
        }

        .button{
            text-align: center;
            width: 50%;
            height: wrap-content;
            margin: auto;
            padding:10px;
            display: flex;
            background-color: #78A3DE;
            color:white;
            font-weight: 200;
            cursor: pointer;
            border:none;
        }

        .button:hover{
            background-color:#78a3de91;
        }

        .pom-area-info-timer{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .pom-area-info-status{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class = 'hero-area'>
        <h1>Good Evening. Yuck exam season!</h1>
    </section>
    <section class = 'pom-area'>
        <button id = "start_pom" class = "button pom-area-start-button">Start Pomodoro</button>
        <div class = 'pom-area-info'>
            <div class = "pom-area-info-timer">
                <h1 id = countdown-timer>25:00</h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "pom-area-info-status">
                STUDY TIME!
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class = 'settings'>
        <button id = "start_settings" class = "button settings-button">Settings</button>
    </section>
    <script src = "./popup_script.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/easytimer/dist/easytimer.min.js"></script>

    <div id="countdownExample">
        <div class="values"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo: sendMessages should be sendMessage.

Comment: Thank you. Well that's how it be huh.